# Golang net/http request Body always empty

Tags: json, web, go

I'm trying to send JSON arguments to my server and parse them using json.Decoder. I've read that you should be able to get the query params from the request.Body property. The following is my server code:

```
func stepHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var v interface{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&v)
    if err != nil {
       // handle error
    }
    log.Println(v)
}
```

Every time, I see `2014/12/26 22:49:23 <nil>` (diff timestamps, of course). My client-side AJAX call is the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/step",
  method: "get",
  data: {
    steps: $("#step-size").val(),
    direction: $("#step-forward").prop("checked") ? 1 : -1,
    cells: JSON.stringify(painted)
  },
  success: function (data) {
    painted = data;
    redraw();
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
    console.log(xhr);
  }
});
```

An example URL of what is sent:

```
http://localhost:5000/?steps=1&direction=1&cells=%5B%7B%22row%22%3A11%2C%22column%22%3A15%7D%2C%7B%22row%22%3A12%2C%22column%22%3A15%7D%5D
```

A nicer look at the params:

```
{
  steps: "1",
  direction: "1",
  cells: "[{"row":11,"column":15},{"row":12,"column":15}]"
}
```

I have tried with both GET and POST requests.

Why does my req.Body never decode? If I try to print req.Body alone, I also see nil.

Comment: It seems to me that `req.Body` is indeed empty -- so why not call `req.ParseForm()` and then use `req.Form` instead?  What gave you the impression that `Body` will somehow get stuff (query parameters) that are definitely **not** in the request's body?

Comment: I seemed to have a misunderstanding of what req.Body referenced. req.Form gives me a map - is there any way to automatically unmarshal the query string into an object?

Comment: @AlexMartelli, I went with your solution. If you create an answer, I can mark it as the resolution to this question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Done @LarryPrice -- and, you're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`req.Body` is indeed empty -- so, what I would do it call `req.ParseForm()` and then use `req.Form` instead. `Body` will not get stuff (such as, query parameters) that's definitely not in the request's body.

Answer (score 1):

The `Body` of a request is sent along inside the payload - it is not part of the URL.

You're attempting to access the body .. when really your data is in the URL.

What you want it to change your ajax `method: "get"` to be `method: "post"` - so that the data is posted along with the body and not as part of the URL. You should also make sure that the data is indeed being sent along with the request via your browser of choice' developer tools. Alternatively, if you really do want your data sent along as part of the URL, you should be accessing the `URL` parameter of the request - and manually parsing the values into a struct (the json package won't do this for you IIRC).

Comment: Json won't do it, but `req.ParseForm()` (then accessing `req.Form`) should do the parsing on your behalf, no?

Comment: Yes - my point was that mapping it to the struct will be a manual process - in contrast to the `Decode` method of the json package.

Comment: I tried changing my method to a POST, and I verified that the data is sent in the body as a payload, but I still get nil every time I try to decode. However, now my Body looks like `&{0xc208020620 <nil> <nil> false {0 0} false}`.

Comment: Can you show us the model you're trying to decode to and any errors you have?