# How to make ajax call with input json data in Jquery and golang?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, curl, go

I am trying to make an ajax call in Jquery but I am getting empty response. But when I try to do the same through curl I am succeeding. Here is my JS,

```
time = new Date($.now());
requestJSON = '{"Method":"GET","AppName":"Proline","ServiceURL":"http://localhost:8081/api/services/tags/","Properties":null,"Object":"","Timestamp":"'+time+'"}'
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8081/api/services/tags/",
  // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
  data: requestJSON,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){alert(data);},
  failure: function(errMsg) {
      alert(errMsg);
  }
});
```

I also tried `dataType: "jsonp"` but no luck.

And the curl command is here,

```
curl --data '{"Method":"GET","AppName":"Proline","ServiceURL":"http://localhost:8081/api/services/tags/","Properties":null,"Object":"","Timestamp":"2016:03:27 00:08:11"}'
-X GET http://localhost:8081/api/services/tags/
```

I have the server code in golang. I already set the header to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*`. Here is my server handler.

```
 func tagsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, extra []string) {
    if origin := r.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
            w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
            w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
            w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "*")
    }
    // Stop here if its Preflighted OPTIONS request
    if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            return
    }
    var response []byte
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("FATAL IO reader issue %s ", err.Error())
    }
    log.Printf("Body : %s ", string(body))
    method    := r.Method
    log.Printf("tagsHandler() :: service method %s ", method)
    if method == HTTP_VERB_POST {
                response = tagslogic.PostTag(body)
    } else if method == HTTP_VERB_GET {
                response = tagslogic.GetTags(body)
    } else if method == HTTP_VERB_PUT {
                response = tagslogic.PutTag(body)
    } else if method == HTTP_VERB_DEL {
            response = tagslogic.DelTag(body)
        }
    w.Write(response)
}
```

To be specific I am getting empty request body in server side.
could someone help me with this?

Comment: I think you don't need to stringify, you are actually stringifying 2 times

Comment: Like @Mir said, `requestJSON` is already a string

Comment: @slash197 - I tried without JSON.stringify but it didnt help :( .

Comment: @slash197 -  I updated the question since that redirects to JSON.stringify issue. I changed JSON.stringify(requestJSON) to requestJSON.

Comment: @DineshAppavoo from your update code, u need stringfy

Comment: @Mir - I tried  `data: JSON.stringify(requestJSON)` ,  `data: JSON.stringify({"Method":"GET","AppName":"howti","ServiceURL":"http://localhost:8081/api/services/tags/","Properties":null,"Object":"","Timestamp":"2016:03:27 00:08:11"})`
 and 
`data: JSON.stringify('{"Method":"GET","AppName":"howti","ServiceURL":"http://localhost:8081/api/services/tags/","Properties":null,"Object":"","Timestamp":"2016:03:27 00:08:11"}')` .  But nothing helped. [In all cases I used JSON.stringify only once. I removed in other places]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the call is not sending the request data in body [But somehow `curl` works fine]. When I try to get the `body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)` it gave empty value. So I changed to get from `r.Form`

```
r.ParseForm()
var body []byte
for key, _ := range r.Form {
    body = []byte(key)
    break
}
```

`r.Form` gives a map. So I am iterating through the map and getting the req data. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664192/golang-net-http-request-body-always-empty) gave the solution.   May be helpful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already stringified in console.log

```
 time = new Date($.now());
    requestJSON = '{"Method":"GET","AppName":"Proline","ServiceURL":"http://localhost:8081/api/services/tags/","Properties":null,"Object":"","Timestamp":"'+time+'"}'
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:8081/api/services/tags/",
      data:JSON.stringify(requestJSON),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){alert(data);},
      failure: function(errMsg) {
          alert(errMsg);
      }
    });
```